# What is Prettier keyboard shortcut command in VS Code to format only a block of React code, not just format on file autosave?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier

Using Prettier: Anyone know the keyboard shortcuts to auto-format a single block of javascript in VSCode on highlight, without having to save the entire file using Prettier to use auto formatting.

Answer (score 19):

On Mac OS for VS Code it's Option+Shift+F

Answer (score 18):

you can create you own default keyboard shortcut in VS code for formatting documents
like in my case prettier code format command is shift+window+F but it is creating issue in mac so i changed the short cut command for it, for more information can refer below screenshots

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9):

Answer: it's make code block selection Command K, F in mac.

Comment: Use `Shift + Alt + f` or `Shift + Alt + F` on windows.   

Go to Preferences => Keyboard Shortcuts. There you can search for "Format Cell" or "Format Document" according to your need and find the shortcut.

Answer (score 9):

Try this...
in ubuntu 20.04:
----vsCode Prettier - Code formatter shortcut- key is ctrl+shift+I

in windows 10,11:
----vsCode Prettier - Code formatter shortcut- key is alt+shift+F